# Where does Clang stores the difference between int32_t *p and int32_t p[10]?

Tags: c++, c, clang

I would like to make sure that this type of code

```
void f1 (int32_t p[10]);
void f2 (int32_t *p);
void b ()
{
    int_32_t a[10];
    f1(a);
    f2(a);
}
```

does not happen when someone is coding, because when using f2(), you may lose the informations about the bounds of the array. It is one of the MISRA Standard rule.

But the AST-dump makes no difference between the 2 functions declaration :

```
|-FunctionDecl 0x2204140 <test.cpp:3:1, col:23> f1 'void (int32_t *)'
  | -ParmVarDecl 0x2204040 <col:10, col:22> p 'int32_t *'
|-FunctionDecl 0x2204280 <line:4:1, col:20> f2 'void (int32_t *)'
  | -ParmVarDecl 0x2204200 <col:10, col:19> p 'int32_t *'
```

I guess that Clang does record somewhere the size of the array (10), but AST-dump seems to inform of the opposite.

Is there some way to differentiate ?

Comment: You can use a `std::vector<int32_t>` and this question goes away :)

Comment: No, the language says that the first is adjusted to the second.

Comment: @Cyber : It's not about what I can use ;) . I am programming a code analyzer, and one of the rules is the one I gave in my question. I want to make sure that the users of my analyzer will not put an array as a parameter for a function asking for a pointer only

Comment: @Marc-O: What's the rationale for this? I'd understand if you wanted to avoid the first version (`void f1 (int32_t p[10]);`), because it may indicate some misconception. Do you mean `void f1 (int32_t p[static 10])`?

Comment: To be clear: there is no information regarding the size of the array in either `f1` and `f2` in C or C++. This makes the question somewhat moot.

Comment: Well like I said on a previous comment, this is one of the MISRA C Standard rules, I guess that MISRA must have a good reason to enforce this rule. The printed example is the one given by MISRA in the column "Don't do". In the column "Do" you can fan this code : 

`void f1 (int32_t (&p)[10]);`
`void b ()`
`{`
  `int32_t a[10];`
  `f1(a);`
`}`

Comment: Your example is C++. In C, you had to do `void f1(int32_t (*p)[10]); void b(void) { int32_t a[10]; f1(&a); }` and this declaration of `f1` _is_ different from `f1(int32_t **p)` and `f1(int32_t p[10])`.

Comment: Sorry, what is MISRA telling you not to do? Is it `void f1 (int32_t p[10]);`? If so, it makes sense, it is a confusing way to say `void f1 (int32_t* p);`. Some of their rules actually make some sense.

Comment: @Marc-O, base on your comment, the MISRA guideline says you should declare functions to take a _reference_ to an array, which preserves the size information. In your original question the array is passed as a pointer, which does not preserve the size information. `int32_t (&p)[10]` declares `p` as a reference to an array of size 10.

Comment: No, MISRA tells us not to give an array as parameter for a function asking for a simple pointer. 

Here is the exact definition of the rule : 

Rule MISRA 5-2-12  : Deterioration of an array in a pointer. (C++ code only)
Description : An variable of type array must not be deteriorated in a pointer. Informations about bound are lost in that case.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Ok I didn't know that C++ could record the size of an array, but only by reference. But in that case, I will never be able to know if a function declaration contains parameters asking for an array right ?

Comment: You may have to write your own parser and semantic analyser for this specific case (or you may be able to wrestle this information from clang *before* it builds the AST.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The question seems to be based on a misconception. This function declaration

```
void f1 (int32_t p[10]);
```

is exactly the same as

```
void f1 (int32_t* p);
```

The parameter is a pointer in both cases. There is no size information kept anywhere.

Note that, in C++, you are allowed to have function parameters that are references to an array of a certain size. For example,

```
void f3(int (&p)[10]);
```

This signature is not the same as the `f1` and `f2` shown in your example.

Comment: The size information is kept by the compiler in order to show error messages, then, once copiled this information is *lost*. Isn't it?

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster I doubt it. I have seen no compiler do that, because at the language level *there is no size information*. If you have a counter example I'd be interested to know.

Comment: I have no such example of my guess, it's only... you know: a guess.

Comment: Even the best of us get it wrong sometimes - http://www.tedunangst.com/flak/post/how-to-screw-up-crypto-the-easy-way (plain old C, not C++)

Comment: @loreb Ha, schoolboy error! But I wonder who thought it would be a good idea to allow this false array parameter syntax in C. I'm sure that it's done far more damage than good.

Answer (score 1):

> I guess that Clang does record somewhere the size of the array (10), but AST-dump seems to inform of the opposite.

Your guess is wrong.

> Is there some way to differentiate ?

No. There is no difference according to the rules of C and C++. See http://www.c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptrparam.html

Answer (score 1):

I think you're attacking the problem from the wrong end. The declarations of the functions are equivalent, but that's not a problem since the rule you're after applies to the *call site*. At the *call site* you certainly know that the array is passed to a function that takes a pointer and doesn't take the array size in another parameter. From the call site's perspective, both `f1` and `f2` calls are semantically the same. They are *equally* safe or unsafe.

The C standard doesn't require the compiler to preserve array bounds information when passing arguments into a function. If there are any array bounds in the function's parameter declarations, they are for human consumption only. The `f1` and `f2` calls are exactly the same according to MISRA, and they are both wrong. You need to pass both the pointer and the array size explicitly.

If you wish to make a special diagnostic for when `f1` is called with a pointer or an array smaller than given size, you'll have to modify the parser and add a custom annotation to the AST. That information could then be picked up by your analyzer.

For any of this to make any sense, you'd also need to add diagnostics when static code analysis indicates that the argument is indexed past the bounds within `f1`.